# I want to print a line from a text file along with a variable

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I want to print off a line from a text file along with a variable I have created on the same line. My code looks like this.

```
print (lines[a] + answer)
```

The `lines [a]` is a random line from a text file I have created, `answer` is a variable I have created when I run this code it appears like like

```
"What is your favorite color,
red"
```

I want it to print off like this

```
"What is your favorite color, red"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP should [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: You can try this, as I think its the leading newline thats causing the problem :

    print(lines[a].replace('\n', '') + str(answer))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
print("%s %s" % (lines[a].rstrip(), answer))
```

Look at documentation: [**str.strip([chars])**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) or even [**str.rstrip([chars])**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.rstrip).

Comment: Cheers for that, I know it might be simple but I am a bit new to coding :) Cheers for that